# Adding div tag to GWT InlineHyperlink

Tags: gwt

What's the correct way to add

`<div class="GFPVJEUDHL GFPVJEUDHEB badge-for-user"></div>`

to a GWT InlineHyperlink object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
new InlineHyperlink(new SafeHtml("<div class="GFPVJEUDHL GFPVJEUDHEB badge-for-user"></div>"))
```

But, `GFPVJEUDHL GFPVJEUDHEB` seems to be obfuscated CSS-Classes.

Waht do you really want to do? Wrap a link arround a widget?

[API-Docs: GWT 2.4](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/InlineHyperlink.html)

Comment: Currently I have a <div class = "avatar">, which has 2 children, the div class I listed and <img  class="gwt-InlineHyperlink" ... I would like to make the first child become a child of the second child. The first child shows an image that hides the second - that's my problem